# Java regexp that only matches URLs without protocol and www

Tags: java, regex

I need a rather greedy regex that agressively matches strings that does not begin with any protocol such as "http://" or "ftp://" and at the same time doesn't match strings that begin with a "www" (or both combined, of course). I'm fairly new to Java and regex but I've managed to make up this one (that doesn't work for me):

```
([\w'-]+)\.(com|info|net|org).+
```

However it doesn't seem to match "example.com". It does seem match "example.com/index.php?q=somequery#something". I don't really understand how to create a regex that doesn't give a match if the string begins with a series of characters, in my case "www" or "http://".

Any help is appreciated.

*(P.S I've tried to look for dupes to this question, I however couldn't find one that matches this one perfectly. Very sorry if this is a dupe.)*

Comment: Note: your current RegEx would match whitespace after the domain which is not allowed in a URL. Also, your RegEx *does* match your example, so the issue is in your Java code in *implementing* it. My guess is that you need to double escape before compiling the string to a RegEx object.

Comment: @tenub Hmmm...I've tried it on this site: http://www.regexr.com/ and according to that site it doesn't match... And also it doesn't matter if it lets through whitespaces, my implementation splits a larger string (a chat message) by its whitespaces so I don't think I'll have to worry about that for now at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has `.+` at the end. Which means `any character except \n (1 or more times)`.

But your sample `example.com` doesn't have anything after the `.com`. That's why your regex doesn't match with the sample.

replace the `.+` with `.*` and it will work for you. FYI the `.*` means `any character except \n (0 or more times)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked nicely! Do you perhaps know any good website that lets you test Java 7 regex's online? (And is reliable)

Comment: You can test your regex at here http://regex101.com Java supports PCRE regex. So you can use it without any worry.